# groupByKey of RDD not getting passed through

Tags: scala, apache-spark, tuples, rdd

Have a query regarding `groupByKey` on my RDD. Below is the query I'm trying:

```
rdd3.map{ case(HandleMaxTuple(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11, col12, col13, col14, col15, col16, col17, col18, col19, col20, col21, col22, col23, col24, col25)) => (HandleMaxTuple(col1,col2,col3, col4, col5),(col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11, col12, col13, col14, col15, col16, col17, col18, col19, col20, col21, col22, col23, col24, col25))}.reduceByKey(_+_)
  .map{ case(HandleMaxTuple(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5),(col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11, col12, col13, col14, col15, col16, col17, col18, col19, col20, col21, col22, col23, col24, col25))}.groupByKey
```

The `HandlemaxTuple` case class I've defined to handle a Scala bug of handling more than 22 tuples in a row. Previous question explained here: [number of tuples limit in RDD; reading RDD throws arrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49505241/number-of-tuples-limit-in-rdd-reading-rdd-throws-arrayindexoutofboundsexception)

I wanted to do a `groupBy` on first 5 columns which I'm trying to get reduced into list of keys and then trying a `groupByKey`. Can someone help me out what's wrong with my above approach of `groupByKey`?

My goal is to group by the first 5 columns and then aggregate to get the sum of the 6th, 7th, and 8th columns.

Comment: It's not very clear what you are trying to achieve here. Do you want to do a `reduceByKey` or `groupByKey`? As I understand your question, you want to do them after each other? (since the keys are the same the `groupByKey` won't do anything in that case, the data has already been reduced).

Comment: @Shaido: Well, prior to using the `HandleMaxTuple` method, I was trying to groupBy the rdd with first 5 columns and sum of 6th, 7th & 8th which is my current problem as well. But, after introducing `HandleMaxTuple`, it has become a bit difficult for me to use aggregation. 
In the above question, I tried to convert the first 5 into keys and then using groupBy but that doesn't work out.

Comment: I see, having the first 5 columns as keys and reducing to get the sum of the 6th, 7th and 8th columns should be doable, I will add an answer in a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing the aggregation, if you only want the result of some columns it's best to only select those in the `map`. If these are less than the Scala limitation on tuple length (22) you can simply use tuples, otherwise you would need to create a new `case class` with different length of the one you currently have. In other words, a `case class` for all columns (or those to keep) except for the first 5 columns that are used as key.

Using the first 5 columns as key and aggregating to the the sums of the 6th, 7th and 8th columns can be done as follows; first `map` to select the columns of interest, then do the aggregation.

```
rdd3.map{ case HandleMaxTuple(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _) => 
    ((col1,col2,col3, col4, col5),(col6, col7, col8))
}.reduceByKey((x,y) => (x._1 + y._1, x._2 + y._2, x._3 + y._3))
```

This will give a separate sum for the 6th, 7th and 8th columns separately.

Small example with an RDD with following rows as input:

```
HandleMaxTuple(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
HandleMaxTuple(13,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
HandleMaxTuple(1,2,3,4,5,65,7,8,9,10,11,12)
```

Gives:

```
((13,2,3,4,5),(6,7,8))
((1,2,3,4,5),(71,14,16))
```

Comment: It worked for tuples `<=22`; irony again. Even though I've specified `HandleMaxTuple` for handling this limit of `22`, in the reduceByKey, I've to specify the remaining columns as well not to exclude them in the resulting rdd. And that again gives me `<console>:1: error: too many elements for tuple: 25, allowed: 22`

But your answer explained what I was missing in my approach.

Comment: @knowone Yes, I guess you could create another case class with 5 fewer columns and use that instead of the `(col6, col7, col8)` tuple. Still, I would probably recommend using a dataframe which wouldn't have this constraint (I know you said using RDD was a requirement before so I didn't include that in the answer).

Comment: Thanks Shaido. With DF i already have done it. I'm just trying the same functionality with RDD, hoping to get some optimization done in terms of processing speed.